# How to make a passepartout/frame in p5js

Tags: p5.js

After I create my canvas in p5js with the following code:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 800);
```

How can I add a white passepartout either around the canvas or inside the canvas?

Comment: you can use [`fill()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/fill) to set a transparent fill for the passparteout and [`rect()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rect) to draw the actual rectangle (or rectangles). [`stroke()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/stroke) can be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a frame around the edge of the canvas, another technique would be to draw a wide line on each margin:

```
let _frameW = 50;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 720);
  background(153);
  strokeWeight(_frameW);
  stroke(209);
  line(0, _frameW/2, width, _frameW/2);
  line(_frameW/2, 0, _frameW/2, height);
  line(0, height - _frameW/2, width, height - _frameW/2);
  line(width - _frameW/2, 0, width - _frameW/2, height);
}

function draw() {
}
```